# How to put an arbitrary number of row/tuples on chosen number of pages on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, storage, rows, pgadmin, fillfactor

I would like to insert a number of rows into a table and be able to specify to PostgreSQL the number of pages that will be used for that number of rows.

e.g: 3000 Rows into 120 Pages.

I know i can change the fillfactor to specify how much the pages should be filled, i can use that or there is another way?
Also if that's possible, how can i evenly distribute the rows into that number of pages?

Comment: "*how can i evenly distribute the rows into that number of pages*" - Postgres will already try to do that

Comment: If you know about how big the rows are, then fillfactor is the way.  But why?